# Putting normal letters in between Greek ones

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols

So I am trying to write out Gauss' law for gravitation and I am having a hard time figuring out how to write it out without an error.

I am currently trying to write in an equation block

```
4\piG\rho\delta
```

but obviously TeX is picking up on the fact that I have `\piG` and not `\pi`. I can delineate between the two by adding a `\`  to space them out but that looks funky in the equation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What makes G any more "normal" than π?

Answer (score 9):

Spaces in math mode are ignored and replaced with the appropriate surrounding space required for each component (like a relational or binary operator, or atom). So, you should be fine with

```
4 \pi G \rho \delta
```

although technically `4\pi G\rho\delta` would suffice.

[image]

Comment: As an aside, π should be written in upright style, using e.g. `\piup` from txfonts package, instead of `\pi`. (By standards, symbols of mathematical constants are written in upright style, not italic, and this is generally applied in physics, though very often violated in mathematics.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Depends on your subject area: pure mathematicians don't use upright for pi/e/d, while more applied areas do at least for d. (Yes, I know that the ISO says they should all be upright.)

Comment: From my physics reading I would say the rule is obeyed for "e", "d" and other Latin alphabet "constants", but the glyph given by `\pi` is the most common symbol for 3.14... for work produced in LaTeX and even some quite old books.

Comment: I've never heard of that before and therefore used `\pi` and so on, where can this ISO be found? wikipedia only covers subscripts, symbols for units and numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0#Mathematical_signs_and_symbols).

Comment: It’s ISO 80000-2 (and IEC 80000-2) now, available from usual ISO document distributors. And as I wrote, though mathematicians have their own habits, in physics the standard is generally followed, and the formula here is clearly a physics formula.